# multiple form calculator event handler

Tags: javascript

The link below will take you to my example. My question is... without changing any code inside the forms themselves can I have one button control all of the buttons in each and every form. So that once the "master button is clicked it will tabulate all of the calulations in each form respectively? You will notice that I only have three forms but the project I am working on will have hundreds. This is simply a small portion of that for the sake of simplicity. What I am hoping some one can answer is if I can have a "master calc" button be clicked rather than clicking the calc button in each form?

http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/1/

Help would be greatly appreciated,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps: [jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/9/n](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDFY/9/)

Basically:

```
function calculateAll() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++ ) {
        CalculateIMSUB(forms[i].input_A.value, forms[i].input_B.value,forms[i], 96)                
    }
}
```

Although I am unsure why the '96' was fed into the CalculateIMSUB function in your example

Comment: thank you very much sq2. the '96' was just a number that I choice for the calculateimsub.

Comment: I have another question similar to this If you could help that would be awesome.                                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870042/javascript-submitting-forms-and-processing

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you could add a **class** to each of your buttons (without having to modify the HTML):

```
$('form button').addClass('autoClick');
```

Then on the master button click:

```
$('.autoClick').click();
```